# $GLOBALS['TSFE']->set_no_cache() is not working From typo3 version 6.2.17 onwards

Tags: php, typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I have called global 'set_no_cache' function in intialize action in my extesion.

```
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->set_no_cache();
```

but unfortunately it is not working From typo3 version 6.2.17 onwards
So Is there any alternative solution?
If you have any idea then please share.

Comment: I never needed this. What do you need that for?

Comment: is your extension piBase or extBase?

Comment: my extension is extBase.

Answer (score 3):

Please note that set_no_cache completely disables any output cache in TYPO3. You most certainly dont need that while developing and should never set it in productive systems.
You can control what actions are cached and which aren't in the ext_localconf.php of your extension.

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'Vendor' . $_EXTKEY,
    $pluginName
    $controllerActionCombinations,
    $uncachedActions
);
```

Basically, you just state your controllers actions in either  `$controllerActionCombinations` or `$uncachedActions` to set up wether they're cached. Look up this Reference page for more information: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/Extbase/Reference/FrontendPlugins.html

If you really need to put a system into uncachable mode, I found it to be a good practice to bind that to the development context as a Typoscript condition in your setup like so:

```
[applicationContext = Development]
    config.no_cache = 1
[end]
```

More information on these conditions regarding Application Context here: http://usetypo3.com/application-context.html

Comment: Good remark, great information source. I didn't know that one. Updated in the answer.

Comment: Nice. But you didn't quite made it a link ;)